# Stuck with matching input signal to an active filter

Tags: circuit-design, filter

I’m stuck at a point when trying to use [this](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1064fb.pdf) filter or a similar one from the same family.

To illustrate the matter I have drawn the below two diagrams. Below **F** represents the filter.

[image]

My aim was to achieve the filtering as in Fig1. But unfortunately the bipolar input signal Vs will be between -10V and +10V as well as the output. And these filters can be supplied from a max range of +8V and -8V power rails not more than that.

The only solution I could come up with is Fig2 at the moment. Op1 halves the input signal to +/-5V voltage range and Op2 doubles the halved signal back to +/-10V range at the filter output. Reg1 and Reg2 are 7.5V or 8V positive and negative voltage regulators respectively.

So as you see this needs four more active components which each can contribute noise as well. Op1 and Op2 might also introduce error. I really dont like this solution but could not think of an alternative.

Is there a workaround for such problem?

Comment: The workaround I would use is to just use a different filter IC or passive filter network.

Comment: The filter I need is variable one through oscillator freq. with high order. So a special family and control. I couldnt find any alternative IC with higher voltage power rails.

Comment: Do you know a very precise way of halving or doubling the voltage? My greatest concern is error from that.

Comment: @cm64 A resistor divider (possibly followed by a buffer) to halve it, using high precision resistors or a matched resistor network, and then a precision op amp circuit to double it. These are very common tasks and not terribly difficult.

Comment: Depending on the input impedance of the filter, the gain-of-0.5 stage could be a resistor divider rather than an active circuit. So no active circuits to introduce noise. But of course in a really low-noise circuit, resistors add noise too. Or the filter could be designed to divide its input by 2 before it touches the op-amp.

Comment: My dream was to use this particular one with a +-10V range https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/10641fa.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find a different component that fills the need: I would try to rethink the whole signal chain and see if you can get away with a lower voltage overall and just using an x2 stage at the end of it. A 3dB penalty on SNR is rather easy to compensate for and you could reduce power consumption by a factor of 4. You would have less overall error this way.

But otherwise I don't see any other alternative. But you don't need (or even want) an op-amp to do the initial ÷2. A passive network of resistors and/or capacitors is more than enough. That means that you only need 1 amplifier to get you back to your desired signal levels.

A matched resistor array that can be matched down to 0.1% or better would take care of most precision errors in both your divider and your amplifier.

To avoid loading the input resistive divider by the input impedance of the filter you have two alternatives:

1. Incorporate the output impedance of the divider into your filter design (preferred solution).
2. Make the output impedance of the divider low enough to be of no consequence to the filter (would unavoidably introduce a systematic error that should be taken into consideration).

Regardless, you might want to use the output impedance of the divider as part of an anti-alias filter, which is advisable in any switched-capacitor configuration.

Comment: Depending on the input impedance of the filter, that initial halving might need a buffer.

Comment: @Hearth the LTC1064 has op-amps in its inputs and, although the suggested configurations are inverting, the suggested input resistors are >20kΩ. Which you could directly incorporate in the divider itself. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Output impdance of the Vs can also be upto 10k. So active attenuation would be better imao. Vs can be any transducer with +-10V range but output impedance might vary.

Comment: @cm64 the only way to do "active attenuation" for the purpose you describe, is to place a voltage buffer before a passive attenuator. The only form of truly "active attenuation" is an inverting amplifier configuration, which has exactly the same input impedance problem as a passive attenuator. You would have the same problem just trying to interface with the filter IC.

Comment: Yes I agree it is still problem even for Fig1 in question. Btw I came across this design http://www.freqdev.com/products/inst/950.html#950 The input is +-10V but the ICs are not named. There is no attenution in their diagram it seems like says 20V p-p. Maybe there are ICs which can work for such rail voltages:(